# Ubuntu 12.04 wireless (wifi) not working, can not upgrade to 12.10, touchpad gestures not working. What to do?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 12.10, upgrade, touchpad

I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS 3 days ago and since then wireless feature and touchpad gestures are not working. Tried everything on internet but still unsuccessful. I cant upgrade to ubuntu 12.10.
These are the following comments I tried. Please help me.

EDIT: just realized usb 3.0 is also not working.

```
COMMAND
lsb_release -r
OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Release:    12.04
-----------------------------------------------------------------

COMMAND
lspci
OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
07:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0f:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
Linux ritwik-PC 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 17:46:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:225d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
0f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:217f]
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
lsusb
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
iwconfig
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
rfkill list all
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
lsmod
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224215  1 
bnep                   18281  2 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bluetooth             180113  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
nls_cp437              16991  1 
vfat                   17585  1 
fat                    61512  1 vfat
snd_hda_intel          33719  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97275  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
nouveau               775039  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ttm                    76949  1 nouveau
uvcvideo               72627  0 
snd                    79041  15 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 nouveau
psmouse                98051  0 
drm                   241971  3 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 nouveau
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
hp_wmi                 18092  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
video                  19651  1 nouveau
wmi                    19256  2 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
r8169                  62190  0 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
sudo su
modprobe -v ath9k
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko 

-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
do-release-upgrade
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]                                                                                                        
Err Upgrade tool                                                                                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]                                                                                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'quantal.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMAND
sudo modprobe ath9k
dmesg | grep ath9k

NO OUTPUT FOR THEM

COMMAND
dmesg | grep -e ath -e 80211
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
[   13.232372] type=1400 audit(1408867538.399:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=975 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.232615] type=1400 audit(1408867538.399:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=975 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.186599] ath3k: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -110
[   15.186635] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   88.219329] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   88.351665] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   88.351667] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   88.351670] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   88.351671] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   88.351673] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   88.351674] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   88.351675] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
-------------------------------------------------------------------

COMMAND
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 python-pyudev
Suggested packages:
  python-qt4 python-pyside.qtcore
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 python-pyudev touchpad-indicator
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 84.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,136 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/ precise/main touchpad-indicator all 0.9.3.12-1ubuntu1 [46.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gir1.2-gconf-2.0 amd64 3.2.5-0ubuntu2 [7,098 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main python-pyudev all 0.13-1 [30.5 kB]
Fetched 84.1 kB in 2s (31.6 kB/s)                                                   
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-gconf-2.0.
(Reading database ... 169322 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gir1.2-gconf-2.0 (from .../gir1.2-gconf-2.0_3.2.5-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyudev.
Unpacking python-pyudev (from .../python-pyudev_0.13-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package touchpad-indicator.
Unpacking touchpad-indicator (from .../touchpad-indicator_0.9.3.12-1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for software-center ...
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:no translation information in database needed
Setting up gir1.2-gconf-2.0 (3.2.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-pyudev (0.13-1) ...
Setting up touchpad-indicator (0.9.3.12-1ubuntu1) ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------

COMMAND
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar jxvf compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
sudo su
./scripts/driver-select ath9k

OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing new driver-select request...
Backing up makefile: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/wireless/ath/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/ssb/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/bcma/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/misc/eeprom/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
NEXT COMMAND
make
OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/.config /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/build M=/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-67-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat/main.o
In file included from /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:64:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/include/linux/compat-3.4.h:32:21: error: redefinition of ‘kmalloc_array’
include/linux/slab.h:243:21: note: previous definition of ‘kmalloc_array’ was here
make[3]: *** [/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-67-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
NEXT COMMAND
make install
OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/build M=/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-67-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat/main.o
In file included from /home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:64:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/include/linux/compat-3.4.h:32:21: error: redefinition of ‘kmalloc_array’
include/linux/slab.h:243:21: note: previous definition of ‘kmalloc_array’ was here
make[3]: *** [/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc/compat] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ritwik/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-67-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Not able to find ( drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/hw.c ) or ( drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/hw.h )

Comment: You can't upgrade to 12.10. 12.10 was a dev release and was only supported for a few months. In fact, 13.04 and 13.10 are both EOL as well. 12.04 is a long term support release (lts) and so is 14.04lts. You can upgrade to 14.04 but 12.04 still has support for a couple of more years.

Comment: when I tried to upgrade to 14.04.1 It gave a warning "Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see wiki...WarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?" So I cancelled it. I am a newbie in linux world can anyone recommend me some good flavour of linux(as per my system)? I have hp 15d103tx (installing xubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Is your wired network working?

There's a solution for your problem in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2103062). Instead of upgrading to the unsupoorted, older 12.10, you should rather upgrade to 14.04, which is the current long term supported release. The newer kernel in 14.04 might fix a few of your issues. [Here's a howto](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-server-12-04-to-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html)

Comment: Yes wired network is working fine. I tried to upgrade to 14.04 but it says "Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?"

Comment: I tried the thread you posted, 

check the question again I posted their output too.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are running the version codenamed Precise, you attempted to install the backports version for Lucid. It isn't available in the Precise repositories. I suggest you try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Your wireless should now be working.